# Jquery Datepicker dd-mm-yy in django

Tags: django, jquery-ui-datepicker

Iam using jquery datepicker in django as my code as :

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

I want the date in dd-mm-yy format. By using `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')`

and `date_of_birth = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)`in forms, i can save the date without any error. But when editing the date it shown in yy-mm-dd format.How can i save the date as dd-mm-yy in database or retrieve as the dd-mm-yy format from database?

Anyone kindly advise?

Answer (score 1):

I got what iam looking for. I Changed the language code in the settings as LANGUAGE_CODE = 'eng'. (European date format)It works...

Answer (score 0):

use input_formats keyword argument of [DateField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django models form please use  input_formats

Comment: iam using custom form with formset factory and not model form.. Is there any solution?